# Why can't I use the groupby function to calculate the average of another column here?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find the average CTR for a set of emails which I would like to categorize by the time that they were sent in order to determine if the CTR is affected by the time they were sent. But for some reason, pandas just doesn't want to let me find the mean of the CTR values.

As you'll see below, I have tried using the mean function to find the mean of the CTR for each of the times, but I continually get the error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

This to me would imply that my CTR figures are not integers or floats, but are instead strings. However, though they came in as strings, I have already converted them to floats. I know this too because if I use the sum() function in lieu of the average function, it works just fine.

The line of code is very simple:

```
df.groupby("TIME SENT", as_index=False)['CTR'].mean()
```

I can't imagine why the sum function would work and the mean function would fail, especially if the error is the one described above. Anyone got any ideas?

EDIT: Code I used to turn CTR column from string percentage (85.8%) to float:

```
i = 0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i, "CTR"] = float(row['CTR'].strip('%'))/100
    i += 1
```

Link to df.head() : https://ethercalc.org/zw6xmf2c7auw

Comment: `sum()` works on string, `mean()` doesn't. To be precise: `pd.Series(['a','b']).sum()` gives `'ab'`.

Comment: But when I use `sum()`, I get floats back, so it appears that my percentages are indeed floats.

Comment: check ```df.dtypes``` to see the types of all your columns, then report back.

Comment: Hm... It says object, but then how come I can add them together? I tried to use this script to turn them into floats, but did I fail?

`i = 0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i, "CTR"] = float(row['CTR'].strip('%'))/100
    i += 1`

EDIT: Added a clearer version of above code to original question.

Comment: Can we see ```df.head()```? It's really hard to help you without seeing the actual df, and if we can't can you make a df that represents your actual data?

Comment: Got it--just added a link to the body of original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['CTR']= (df['CTR'].str.strip('%').astype('float'))/100
```

The above code strips the % from the CTR column, then changes its type to float.You can then do your groupby.